# How many hours can a minor do in Minnesota?

Tags: salary, united-states, work-time

I’m 16 years old, and soon will be turning 17 (July 7th).

This summer, when school gets out, I will be applying at Target which is about a minute walk from where I live.

Am I able to work full time at 40+ hours a week or is there a law for minors about that kind of thing? Research into the topic varies, and a lot is outdated because it seems to change often.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78170/discussion-on-question-by-hobo-warrior-how-many-hours-can-a-minor-do-in-minnesot).

Answer (score 9):

> How many hours can a minor do in Minnesota?

By state law, 16- and 17-year-old high school students may not work after 11 p.m. on evenings before school days or before 5 a.m. on school days. With written permission from a parent or guardian, these hours may be expanded to 11:30 p.m. and 4:30 a.m. No other time limit is set for 16- and 17-year-olds.

Your going to notice as a minor, **most states will focus on you not working in the late night hours versus how many hours you work**, especially if school is out.

Reference [MN Department of Labor](http://www.dli.mn.gov/LS/WorkHours.asp)

Also see this regarding teen workers: [MN Teen Workers](http://www.dli.mn.gov/LS/TeenWorkers.asp)

Editing to add the relevant text from the links, since per Hobo_warrior's comment he is not able to see them:

> Labor Standards -- Child labor:  hours of work
>
> **A minor less than 16 years of age:**
>   A minor less than 16 years of age may not work:
>
> - before 7 a.m. or after 9 p.m.* with the exception of a newspaper carrier;
> - for more than 40 hours a week or more than eight hours per 24-hour period*, except in agriculture;
> - on school days during school hours, without an employment certificate issued by the school district superintendent (Minnesota Statutes 181A.05).
>
> *During the school year, federal law restricts hours to no later than 7 p.m., no more than three hours a day on school days and not more than 18 hours a week.
>
> **A minor age 16 or 17 years old:**
>   By state law, 16 and 17 year old high school students may not work after 11 p.m. on evenings before school days or before 5 a.m. on school days. With written permission from a parent or guardian, these hours may be expanded to 11:30 p.m. and 4:30 a.m. No other time limit is set for 16 and 17 year olds.

Comment: You answered a question concerning curfew but that’s not what I’m asking I’m afraid.

Comment: @Hobo_warrior but that is the only actual law about you working. As a 16 or 17 yearold, you can work any number of hours (as it is not a school day). As I see it for the summer you have no work restrictions. When the school year starts back up and you are 17 you are limited to working till 11 pm

Answer (score 8):

Both your school and any potential employer such as Target should know.  My 15 year old worked an entire summer at ValleyFair plus a part-time fall gig as a monster at ValleyScare and there was not a problem with max hours.

Especially Target, as they hire a wompload of teenagers and people of various citizenship statuses.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

At that age most places tend to pick based on hours available. When I was 16, I got lucky to find a department store near my house that allowed me to work 5-9pm on Friday and Saturday, then 1-4 on Sunday. I only made like 70 bucks each 2 weeks but it was fun. The only reason they hired me because I happened to put nearly the same hours on my application.

In all future applications, I noticed my manager just looked at the available time part of the application, and just threw out applications that didn't match her hours.

As far as 40 hours, I recall I did work some 40 hours during the summer, but my opinion is that you should wait to work 40 hours a week and instead opt for a fun summer while making money to buy things and have a good time growing up. You'll never have your youth again and at age 16, working was actually fun for me because I didn't have any bills just fun things to get with friends or family.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to get a decently paying job because my Aunt will take $100 dollars out of each of my paychecks to help pay for her rent...

Comment: @Hobo_warrior Can you not pay your aunt from your other regular job, the one where your boss didn't pay you overtime? Or do you mean she will take $100 from the paycheck of each of your jobs?